# Model Change in reactive form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

In the angular model Form I can show a mask in the field and save a value without the mask in the template. How do I do this with reactive forms?

`maskService.getCNPJ = [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '.', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '.', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/]`

`maskService.unmask = (value) => value.replace(/\D+/g, '')`

**Model Form**

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="data.cnpj" name="cnpj" [textMask]="{mask: maskService.getCNPJ, guide: false}" (ngModelChange)="data.cnpj = maskService.unmask($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides a pattern Validator :

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  phone: ['', Validators.pattern(/* your regex */)]
});
```

If you want to provide a mask, you still can use a custom function for that :

```
<input formControlName="phone" (input)="mask()">
```

In your TS :

```
mask() {
  // Do your masking thing
  this.myForm.get('phone').setValue('your mask value');
}
```